# use paypal to check user real identity

Tags: validation, paypal, identity, account

is it possible, after user join my websites, to validate their identity connecting a paypal account and check if the credit card's name, surname, address match?

Comment: doesn't prove their identity it just shows that their credit card's name, surname, address match the paypal account. Anyway can you see that much data on PayPal? If you can it must help with ID theft.

Comment: yes i want to check if they match

Comment: let's suppose users already join the community filling name, surname, addresses. I just want let them to login into paypal and check, once logged, if paypal name, surname and address, match.

So they only validate choosing it by performin login to paypal, in this way i'm not looking to know paypal passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Heandel said, this is not something you should want. However, an alternative is to do a $1 authorization using Express Checkout. Set PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Authorization, retrieve the token and redirect the user to agree to the $1 authorization charge. Once redirected back to your site, you'll have received a PayerID, which you can use to call GetExpressCheckoutDetails and retrieve some (definitely not all) information.
E.g. first name / last name and email address. In addition, you'll know he/she has a working funding source.

Once satisfied, you can call DoVoid to void the $1 authorization and the user will not be charged anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. The precise goal of Paypal is avoiding this kind of information "leak".

People use Paypal because it allows them to pay WITHOUT communicating their name, surname, address, credit card number, etc, to third party websites.

Comment: so in a professional services community how is it possibile to validate the users identity to accept the services withous pre paid them?

Comment: In essence it is not possible to be certain. If someone wanted to and went to the trouble they could set up a false id, with all the trimmings and you would not be able to tell. Plus there is not "quick online" way of doing it else it would be done. There will be a balance of how much there is to gain (from your site) over how much time it takes to set up the fake id's. But that is only letting you have a degree of confidence not certainty.